# NodeJS SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 16

Tags: node.js, error-handling, body-parser

I am using `body-parser` middleware in order to handle JSON requests bodies in REST API.

I have tried to "hack" and test how the system handles such an input:

```
// Note the "form": "a" does not include the required ","
{
    "from": "a"
    "destination": "Netanya",
    "date": {
        "start": "15-07-2018"
    }
}
```

Now I do not know where I can catch such an error of bad input syntax.

I have tried to remove the body-parser and error is not thrown, but of course, then I cannot have the data in the `req.body`.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve? Do you want to catch the error in your middleware and return some error (like invalid input)?

Comment: Yes, something like this, in general, I dont want the user to receive such an unappropriate response from the server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/issues/236) and tested below code:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function (error, req, res, next) {
  if(error instanceof SyntaxError){ //Handle SyntaxError here.
    return res.status(500).send({data : "Invalid data"});
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

### UPDATE=========

There are six types of errors:

1. **EvalError:** Raised when the eval() functions is used in an incorrect manner.
2. **RangeError:** Raised when a numeric variable exceeds its allowed range.
3. **ReferenceError:** Raised when an invalid reference is used.
4. **SyntaxError:** Raised when a syntax error occurs while parsing JavaScript code.
5. **TypeError:** Raised when the type of a variable is not as expected.
6. **URIError:** Raised when the encodeURI() or decodeURI() functions are used in an incorrect manner.

Comment: Thanks sir. Where can I find a refernce of all instance of error object?